# How to draw several lines and arcs with different colors?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

In `wxwidgets` I am using `wxGraphicsContext` and `wxGraphicsPath` to draw two arcs. I want them to have different colors:

```cpp
gc->SetPen (wxPen (*wxRED, 8));
path.MoveToPoint (x, y);
path.AddArc (x, y, radius, angle_rad_1a, angle_rad_1b, true);  // X, Y, radius, start angle, end angle, clockwise
gc->SetPen (wxPen (*wxBLUE, 4));
path.MoveToPoint (x, y);
path.AddArc (x, y, radius, angle_rad_2a, angle_rad_2b, true);  // X, Y, radius, start angle, end angle, clockwise
gc->StrokePath (path);
```

But it all comes out in blue with 4 pixels width.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Xaviou wrote you need a gc->StrokePath() for every pen setting.
And you need a gc->CreatePath() for every gc->StrokePath().
So the code that does the job looks like this:

```
  path = gc->CreatePath();
  gc->SetPen (wxPen (*wxRED, 8));
  path.MoveToPoint (x, y);
  path.AddArc (x, y, radius, angle_rad_1a, angle_rad_1b, true);  // X, Y, radius, start angle, end angle, clockwise
  gc->StrokePath (path);
  path = gc->CreatePath();
  gc->SetPen (wxPen (*wxBLUE, 4));
  path.MoveToPoint (x, y);
  path.AddArc (x, y, radius, angle_rad_2a, angle_rad_2b, true);  // X, Y, radius, start angle, end angle, clockwise
  gc->StrokePath (path);
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

The path is drawn with the active pen when you call gc->StrokePath, not before.
So the first pen selection has no effect.

Comment: I tried that as well, adding a StrokePath after the first AddArc, but with the same result. Now from your answer I come to think it may be that then the first StrokePath uses the first pen setting and the second StrokePath uses the second pen setting but it writes the complete path including also the first arc, thus overwriting what was drawn with the first pen setting. Can this be the case? So I would need a reset or clear of the path. Does such a command exist?

Comment: I can confirm that it is as descrided above. The only solution I found is having a gc-> CreatePath() for every gc->StrokePath().